# Get emoji working in tkinter and make it overridable by code but not end user during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, unicode, emoji

I need to create a field in tkinter that stores an emoji but when someone presses a button, that emoji is overwritten. I can't get emojis working in tkinter and I'm not sure how to then overwrite it.

```py
import tkinter as tk

self.option4 = tk.Button(self, width=10)
self.option4["text"] = "no"
self.option4["command"] = self.wrong
self.option4.pack(side="top")

corecalc = ""

self.answercheck = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=5)
self.answercheck.pack()
self.answercheck.insert(tk.END, corecalc)

self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

def correct(self):
  corecalc = "✅"

def wrong(self):
  corecalc = "❌"
```

Expected  outputs in field and changes to ❌ upon button press. Also is there a better method than text box that makes the field fixed rather than editable by end user.

Error: `_tkinter.TclError: character U+1f532 is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl`

Comment: What are these `self.something` outside a class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any tkinter widget to display the characters - emojis or otherwise, that you will need - a `Text` widget if you want to display a single character is a poor choice, though possible.

If you really want to use `Text`, you can change it to not editable by setting its `state` Key to "disabled" (as oposed to the default "normal"):

```
self.answercheck = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=5, state="disabled")
```

A text box will require you to remove the previous text before insertig the new, you can simply use a `tkinter.Label` widget if you want programtic only changes to the characters:

```py
import tkinter as tk

w = tk.Tk()
display = tk.Label(w, text="□")
display.pack()

def correct():
  display["text"] = "✅"

def wrong():
  display["text"] = "❌"


button = tk.Button(w, text="no", command=wrong)
button.pack()
button = tk.Button(w, text="yes", command=correct)
button.pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

(In the build I have here - Python 3.7 on a Linux fedora, tkinter can't handle your  character directly, as its codepoint is above \uffff)